# jQuery UI Draggable: horizontal Scroll not working on move first column to last column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable, sortablejs

I have a strange issue with jQuery ui-sortable. In my example I have multiple columns and in each column I have multiple sortable items.

I want to drag and drop in any column, sorting within one column is no problem.

Horizontal scroll does not scroll for the first column to very right side column.

```
var configuration2 = {
        cursor : 'move',
        placeholder : 'highlight',
        dropOnEmpty : true,
        connectWith : ".connectedSortable",
        containment : "body",
    };

    $(".connectedSortable").sortable(configuration2).disableSelection();
```

See my example https://jsfiddle.net/maidanhcongtu/9ws2unLa/11/

Comment: When I remove max height and overflow like this https://jsfiddle.net/maidanhcongtu/9ws2unLa/10 it's working. is this case horizontal scroll working. how can I archive that?.